# Merging Duplicate Records From Two Tables Into One Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables as describe bellow:

[image]

How can I perform a query to merge the duplicate data in table B, so I can get table C in which the records derived from table A and Table B?

Any help will by highly appreciated..
Thank You !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using `UNION`

```
SELECT ID, Value FROM TableA
UNION
SELECT ID, Value FROM TableB
```

if there is an extra table named `TableC` and you want to insert the result of `TableA` and `TableB`, use `INSERT INTO...SELECT` statement,

```
INSERT INTO TableC(ID, Value)
SELECT ID, Value FROM TableA
UNION
SELECT ID, Value FROM TableB
```

---

Or maybe you want to create a `VIEW`

```
CREATE VIEW TableC
AS
SELECT ID, Value FROM TableA
UNION
SELECT ID, Value FROM TableB
```

to call the View,

```
SELECT * FROM TableC
```

Comment: Thank you J W, it work fine. I just wondering how to make sure the result is correct like in table C? You know, I'm handling such tables that contains huge and very sensitive data. Anyway, I will test up it in another database that contains smaller data. Thank again J.W